# How do I set a backupdir and swap directory stored locally to a working directory using a ./ relative path in Vim?

Tags: vim

**Summary:**
I'm trying to get Vim to store **backup** files, **swap** files, and **undo** files in a directory relative to the working directory so that I can move those files with the working directory (such as on a USB stick).

**Background:**
I wrote a function that sets the `backupdir`, `directory`, and `undodir` settings when Vim first starts up. I set the settings to initially look for **relative paths** in the working directory **first** (which would be on a USB stick), then look for a centralized directory in `~/vim/scratch_files/`, a centralized directory that I would rather not use if a relative path is available.

However, no matter what relative paths I put, Vim just insists on using the centralized path, whether testing on Linux or Windows Vim installations.

**Research:** I've checked the help files (in `:help backupdir`), Vim Fandom pages, and Stack Exchange, and have searched for solutions and couldn't find anything that makes it work.

**EXAMPLE:** Here is a minimally working example of what I'm talking about. I have a line in my .vimrc that adds a file, say for instance `scratchfiles.vim`, to the runtimepath variable with the following code:

```
    function! SetLocalScratchFiles()
        " Turn the settings on
        set backup
        set writebackup
        set swapfile

        if has("win32") || has("win64")
            " The // gets replaced with a %-substituted path for a filename in the destination scratch file in Windows as per :h backupdir (i.e., C%%path%to%file.txt.swp)
            set backupdir^=.\\_scratch\\backup//,.\\.scratch\\backup//,$HOME\\.vim\\scratch_files\\backup//,.
            set directory^=.\\_scratch\\swap//,.\\.scratch\\swap//,$HOME\\.vim\\scratch_files\\swap//,.
        else
            set backupdir^=./_scratch/backup//,./.scratch/backup//,~/.vim/scratch_files/backup//,.
            set directory^=./_scratch/swap//,./.scratch/swap//,~/.vim/scratch_files/swap//,.
        endif
        " Undo Directory:
        if has('persistent_undo')
            if has("win32") || has("win64")
                set undodir^=.\\_scratch\\undo//,.\\.scratch\\undo//,$HOME\\.vim\\scratch_files\\undo//,.
            else
                set undodir^=./_scratch/undo//,./.scratch/undo//,~/.vim/scratch_files/undo//,.
            endif
            set undofile
        endif
    endfunction
    autocmd VimEnter * call SetLocalScratchFiles()
```

It's supposed to (a) look for local directory relative to the present working directory called `./_scratch/` for subdirectories /backup/, /swap/ and /undo/. Then, if that's not found, (b) look for the same subdirectories in `./.scratch/`. THEN if that's not found, use `~/.vim/scratch_files/`.

**QUESTION:**

The problem is that no matter how many different types of relative paths I feed these settings, Vim always picks the one centralized directory. How can I get it to **recognize these relative paths first**? Is there something wrong with the way I've formatted the paths, perhaps?

Comment: Do the directories `./{_,.}scratch/{backup/,swap/,undo/}` exist? `vim` doesn't create them, it will use the first one that exist. Also verify that after `vim` started and loaded the file to edit the options have correct values: `:set backupdir? directory? undodir?`

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, they do exist in the working directory and in all subdirectories, and the scratch directories all have the same 3 subdirectories, and all of them are empty when I open a bunch of files and make changes in the same directory.

Comment: Here's similar output after doing `:redir @a` then `set [setting]?` on all 3 settings, then `:redir END`: 

```backupdir=.\_scratch\backup//,.\.scratch\backup//,~\.vim\temp_dirs\backup//,.,.,~\AppData\Local\Temp,c:\tmp,c:\temp```

```directory=.\_scratch\swap//,.\.scratch\swap//,~\.vim\temp_dirs\swap//,.,.,~\AppData\Local\Temp,c:\tmp,c:\temp```

```undodir=.\_scratch\undo//,.\.scratch\undo//,~\.vim\temp_dirs\undo//,.,.```

Comment: I think `backupdir` and `undodir` shouldn't end with `//`, only `directory` should. What directories `vim` uses with your settings?

Comment: It uses the final one, ~\.vim\scratch_files (in my previous comment temp_dirs, but scratch files in this example). Are you sure? Because it does talk about the // in the help section for `backupdir` and `undodir` so I used it. I can take it out and see if it fixes the problem, however.

Comment: Okay, I edited my files and it did not fix it. Perhaps it's because I have it inside of a function that activates with `VimEnter` using `autocmd`? I could try taking it out of this.

Comment: I don't see `//` in [`backupdir`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'backupdir') or [`undodir`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'undodir'). A function shouldn't prevent `:set` to work — the settings are global, the command `:set …?` show settings.

Comment: Aha, found it in newer docs: [`backupdir`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27backupdir%27). vim 8.1? I'm still on 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I figured it out! It has to do with the firing rate of Autocmd vs setting the settings in Vimrc, being called sooner than an autocmd command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was putting these settings inside of a function that is called by `autocmd VimEnter * ...` -- after removing the first and last two lines from the previous code, the local directories are recognized and the correct relative paths are set. I believe has to do with the order in which Vim handles autocmd's. It must fire those off after looking at the vanilla settings in the vimrc.

The bottom line is not to set `backupdir`, `undodir`, or `directory` via `VimEnter` since these need to be set sooner than when `VimEnter` is called.